# Async method testing using XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I am new to XCTest and started writing test cases. I have written couple of functional test cases, but I got stuck in below async method call. I read XCTestExpectation class reference but not able to mock properly.

It will be really helpful If get to know how to test below method.

Here are the details of method that I want to test,

```
- (void)getStudentInfo:(void (^)(BOOL))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {


   // Request formation CODE
   // Here I have post call to AFNetworking

    [httpSessionManager POST:uri
   parameters:para
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
       }]



  }
```

Comment: Although there are techniques for async testing with unit tests, in general asynchronous processes and unit testing are not a good match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into XCTest expectations which provide support for async testing. Here is a simplified example (in Swift, but the same applies for Objective-C)

```
func testAsync() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Waiting for something")

    let someObject = ...
    someObject.doSomethingWithCompletion({ () in
            expectation.fulfill()
        })

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3.0, handler: nil)

    // Verify Results
}
```

The simple explanation is that the test will wait at the `waitFor...` until the `fulfil()` method is called. Or timeout and throw an error.

You can also set expectations on notifications and properties. Check the XCTest class doco for details.